# Create an EKEvent with specific calendarEventID

Tags: ios, ios11, ekevent

Is it possible to create an event in the calendar with a chosen identifier?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/eventkit/ekevent/1507437-eventidentifier) for EKEvent.eventIdentifier, it clearly states that the property is generated and **get-only**.

> If the calendar of an event changes, its identifier most likely changes as well.

It is **not meant to be manipulated** in any way, since it serves to identify each event uniquely.